# Angular2 async calls

Tags: asynchronous, angular

I'm facing a classic http race issue, but I'm not familiar enough with Angular2 and Observable to resolve my case.

Here's a description of my bricks :

```
[ FormComponent ]
    |    |
   1|    |6
    |    |
[ MetadataService ] <----4 & 5----> [ TranslatorService ]
    |    |
   2|    |3
    |    |
 [ Backend ]
```

1. My form component asks to the MetadataService the metadatas of the form
2. The Metadataservice makes an HTTP call to the Backend to retrieve these metadata
3. Backend returns the metadatas in JSON format
4. MetadataService transmit the JSON to the TranslatorService
5. TranslatorService make some translations within the JSON and returns an array to the MetadataService
6. MetadataService returns the array to the FormComponent.

The architecture seems simple but there's something wrong in the way I'm implementating this, as in the end in my view the metadata property is "undefined" and therefore *ngFor throws an error
My first idea was to subscribe to the Observable in the component but I don't know how to deal with these Observables as I've got two services.

From my opinion the problem comes from the 4th step :

**MetadataService**

```
getFormMetaData(folderId: string, context: string){
    let body = JSON.stringify({
                   folderId: folderId,
                   context: context
               });
    return this.http.post(this.uri, body, options)
                            .map( (res) => { 
                                    let body = res.json();
                                    if (body.data){
                                        return this.translatorService.getTranslatedElements(body.data);
                                    }
                                } 
                            );
}
```

It should return an Observable, but the map() method return the value of the TranslatorService, which is an array...

How should I do ?

edit : 
Here's is my FormComponent :

**FormComponent**

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <dynamic-form controls="formMetadata | async"></dynamic-form>
    `,
    providers: [MetadataService]
})
export class CustomerFormComponent {

    formMetadata: any; 

    constructor(private metadataService: MetadataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formMetadata = this.formMetadataService.getFormMetadata('FR75P00000012', 'UserInformation');
    }
}
```

And my TranslatorService :

**TranslatorService**

```
getTranslatedElements(metadata: any) {
    debugger; // It never breaks here
    let elements = [];

    metadata.forEach( (field) => { 
        ...
        elements.push(field);
    } ) 

    return elements;

}
```

Update :

Ok, I advanced a bit. It seems the problem comes from my async pipe, that I use in the FormComponent template to pass data to a child component.

Should this child component handle this kind of asyncronous data in a particular manner too ?

**Solution** 
How to waste hours to debug : forget to put your databinded properties inside brackets.

`<dynamic-form controls="formMetadata"></dynamic-form>`

should be

`<dynamic-form [controls]="formMetadata"></dynamic-form>`

That explains why DynamicFormComponent received a string as input...

**Solution 2**
Actually, I still had the problem of having the child component instanciated before even the subscribe function load datas.
I've been able to resolve this by doing a 
`<dynamic-form [controls]="formMetadata" *ngIf="formMetadata"></dynamic-form>`

I couldn't use the async pipe, it didn't work. I don't know when the async trigger within the parent template, but it seems to be after the child component constructor() and noOnInit()

Comment: How are you calling the `MetadataService` in your component?

Comment: @rinukkusu yes I do. The component calls MetadataService, and the MetadataService calls the TranslatorService, which takes a JSON as parameter, pick some rows and return an Array of objects

Comment: I'm asking "how". Could you please add that to your question? :)

Comment: @rinukkusu  Sorry, I've read your comment too fast :). I edited and added some informations at the bottom

Comment: Does the response from the server look correct? Could you add a `console.log(body)` after the `res.json()`

Comment: Yes, the response is what I expected, I forgot to mention that I take the body.data which is already an array (not json). I updated my post again : it seems the problem is how I use the async pipe in my template, actually I pass the data to a child component, with classic `@input()` and databinding. Should the child component do something special on its side ?

Comment: Hm, you could try to either initialize the `formMetadata` to `null` or abandon the async pipe and directly subscribe to it, if you think that's the problem.

Comment: Also I just saw, that you have two different names for the variable in `CustomerFormComponent` - `metadata` and `formMetadata`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126521/discussion-between-dlafcreative-and-rinukkusu).

Comment: Ok, when I try to display the formMetadata property directly on my component : `{{ formMetada | async | json }}`, it works. So the problem comes from the way I pass this async data to the child component. `<dynamic-form controls="formMetadata | async"></dynamic-form> `.

Answer (score 0):

As described in http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html

> The Map operator applies a function of your choosing to each item
>   emitted by the source Observable, and returns an Observable that emits
>   the results of these function applications.

So MetadataService should return an Observable of what returns `this.translatorService.getTranslatedElements(body.data);` 
or an Observable of undefined in case of body.data is empty.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds pretty clear in the theory but in pratical I'm a bit confused. Can I make MetadataService returning an Observable of `this.translatorService.getTranslatedElements(body.data);` ?

Comment: `.map` just modifies the content of the `Observable`. The `return` inside the `.map` only returns the value for the lambda not the whole method, that calls the `.post`.

Comment: Yes. Import Observable and try to return Observable.of(this.translatorService.getTranslatedElements(body.data));

Comment: I think @rinukkusu is right, effectively I already have an Observable object returned by my `http.post()`,  so ok `.map just modifies the content of the Observable. In my component, I bind this cold Observable directly to my view so that the async pipe subscribe. Still I have a `controls.forEach is not a function(…)`

Comment: Is 'formMetadata' declared as Observable in the FormComponent?

Comment: and try to define getTranslatedElements(metadata:  []) instead of any

Comment: That's just syntactic sugar, there are no types in the compiled JavaScript.

Comment: Well no, currently it is only declared as : `formMetadata = any;`

Comment: Currently I can't post in chat, my suggestion is to initialize formMetadata with empty array

Comment: I added an interesting comment below my initial post :)

Comment: Has 'dynamic-form' got what it's expected? I'm asking, because json pipe returns string as decribed in [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/JsonPipe-pipe.html)

Comment: No it doesn't. I just debugged further, I have this property in my DynamicForm component `@Input() controls = ControlBase<any>[] = []`. In its constructor, I well have the `controls` property equal to `[]` but it turns out that in the `ngOnInit`, it's suddenly equal to a string `formMetadata`. I have to pass these control to another service which transform these into ng2 FormGroup (inspired from official doc about dynamic form) and it actually breaks inside this

Comment: Resolved. It missed the brackets around attribute since the beginning... `<dynamic-form [controls]="formMetadata"></dynamic-form>`  I'm going to hide myself. Thanks a lot for your help guys

Comment: Not so resolved... I still had my asynchroneous issue, having dynamic-form loaded before my formMetadata. I've been able to resolve that by adding a ngIf `<dynamic-form [controls]="formMetadata" *ngIf="formMetadata"></dynamic-form>`. If you know a better solution :)

Comment: As I said before, try to initialize formMetadata with empty array

Comment: when 'dynamic-form' renders, [controls] will get [] from that variable, and after request it will change to another array with data